# Gradle task that lists dependencies that are managed by spring boot dependencies but has defined a version

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

I'm looking for a way to list dependencies that are managed by a bom (like spring boot dependencies or spring cloud dependencies) but has declared a version when they are imported in gradle. The dependenyManagement task of the spring dependency management plugin lists all dependencies but than i have to check manually if the dependency is in the list. i would like to have a more automated solution to prevent accientally define a version that would be managed by spring.

Comment: Just remove the version manually and rebuild the project